# C - Access Violation when calling external function

Tags: c#, c, dll, access-violation

I have two c libraries A and B (DLL) in visual studio.

Library B depends on functionality exposed by library A. Everything compiles without <s>warnings</s> and errors.

When executing `B.AddAt(...)` an Access Violation gets thrown out at the `A.GetValue(...)` call.

When replacing `A.GetValue(...)` with a local implementation `B.GetValueInternal(...)` everything works just fine.
Note that `B.GetValueInternal(...)` also calls a function defined in library A.

The function gets invoked from a managed environment (C#) like this:

```
[DllImport("B.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern Container AddAt(IntPtr data, Container d, int x, uint size);
```

This is how the c-code looks:

**A.dll**

**A.h**

```
#ifndef EXPORT_API
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif 

#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED
typedef struct Container
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
} Container;

EXPORT_API Container GetValue(Container* data, int x, unsigned int size);
EXPORT_API int Clamp(int value, int min, int max);

#endif
```

**A.c**

```
#include "A.h"

EXPORT_API Container GetValue(Container* data, int x, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int xx = Clamp(x, 0, size - 1);

    return data[xx];
}

EXPORT_API int Clamp(int value, int min, int max)
{
    return (value < min) ? min : (value > max) ? max : value;
}
```

**B.dll**

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"

#ifndef EXPORT_API
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif 

#ifndef B_H_INCLUDED
#define B_H_INCLUDED

Container GetValueInternal(Container* data, int x, unsigned int size);
EXPORT_API Container AddAt(Container* data, Container d, int x, unsigned int size);
#endif
```

**B.c**

```
#include "B.h"

Container GetValueInternal(Container* data, int x, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int xx = Clamp(x, 0, size - 1);

    return data[xx];
}

EXPORT_API Container AddAt(Container* data, Container d, int x, unsigned int size)
{
    //Container v = GetValueInternal(data, x, size);// This works
    Container v = GetValue(data, x, size);// This throws Access Violation
    v.a += d.a;
    v.b += d.b;
    v.c += d.c;

    return v;
}
```

What can cause such a behavior? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
Calling code looks as the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Container
{
    public float a;
    public float b;
    public float c;
}

Container d = ... //Some container

// input.NativePointer (IntPtr) points to a valid array of Containers
Container c = AddAt(input.NativePointer, d, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Show the calling code.

Comment: this line, in a.c, will cause a compiler warning: `unsigned int xx = Clamp(x, 0, size - 1);` because `clamp()` returns a `int` but the `xx` variable is declared as `unsigned int`

Comment: strongly suggest stepping through the code with a debugger.  and checking the struct contents returned from `getvalue()`  Also, strongly suggest modifying the code so that `getvalue()` returns a pointer to the entry in the `data[]` array. rather than returning the whole struct found at that pointer

Comment: @EugeneSh. Added calling code. But does this really matters?

Comment: Well, you have hidden the most important stuff again. What is that "valid array" ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry for the vague wording. In this case "valid" means that the content is approved by unit testing on the managed side.